# Multiple relation between two models

Tags: graphql, graphcool

I have two databases/models `User` and `Listing`.

I am trying to create two relations:

- One `User` to *one* `Listing` called "ListingOwner"
- One `User` to **many** `Listing` called "ListingCreator"

My users can create multiple listings. I want to keep that as "Creator". But any user is allowed to come in and "claim" a listing, making them the "Owner". However in graph.cool I can't create more then one relationshp between `User` and `Listing` model, it gives me this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8elX.png

> Server request for mutation `AddRelationMutation` failed for the following reasons: 1. A field with the name 'listing' already exists AddRelationInput!) {addRelation(input:$input_0) {clientMutat ^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A model can only have one field with a given name. In your case the solution would be to rename one of the listing fields to something else. When you create the relation you can change the field name in the ui as below:

[image]

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Very interesting thank you @sorenbs! The screenshot was especially helpful! As otherwise I wouldn't have known what that meant, I am very new to graphql. Thanks sir!

Comment: Your welcome Notidart :-) Keep asking questions as you explore GraphQL!